# Sprite Kit - Slide physical body over others

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I am developing a game with swift Sprite kit. But I've got a problem, as you can see in the picture I have a number of physical blocks with the same size aligned. When I slide this block above the others sometimes he gets stuck or do small jumps.
It seems that the physical bodies sometimes overlap.
Anyone know how I can fix it to have a continuous and without inprecision movement?

Some physics characteristics:

```
player.physicsBody?.friction       = 0.0
player.physicsBody?.restitution    = 0.00
player.physicsBody?.linearDamping  = 0.1
player.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0.0
player.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
player.physicsBody?.velocity.dx = 0
player.physicsBody?.velocity.dy = 0
player.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask    = heroCategory
player.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = enemyCategory
player.physicsBody?.density = 2.3
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The problem appears to be just a slight imperfection of physics engine (and hey, it's a simulation, and not completely accurate, I've run into this kind of thing before).  I see that you are preventing rotation of the player, so you can change the physics body of the square `player` into a circle.  This should be something like:

```
player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 10)
```

Replace 10 with the proper radius of your `player`.  This should smooth out the bumps you are encountering.

Comment: I had the same idea at this point my latest version of the Player is an ellipse and improved a lot. But still is not perfect, it's very annoying if an engine problem :(

Comment: @user2838026  Ah, okay, I didn't know that.  Now that I'm thinking about it, if you show the physics in the scene, the way I described should show a low resolution circle (with about 16 vertices).  You may be able to use a `CGPath` which will be a smoother circle.  Something like `player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(polygonFromPath: CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20), nil))`  There also appears to be a rounded rectangle `CGPath` creator that you may need to look into for the terrain if this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

How are you sliding the block?

I've had the same problem and I was able to solve it sliding my hero using SKAction to run a code block that changes the hero's velocity or by just simple running an SKAction.moveBy. Your SKAction should'nt be attempting to push your block against the ground. An action to move the block only in the x direction.

You can also smooth the surface by making sure your physicsBody(s) of ground blocks are not overlapping. Introduce a gap of 1-2 points. Or maybe group tiles with a single physicsBody. This may help as well.